# Why do we need SHA-1 for OAuth client ID?

Tags: android, cordova, security, google-oauth, google-signin

I am creating android app using cordova. And using cordova-plugin-googleplus to use google native signin box.
I had to create SHA-1 from signing cert of my app (currently using debug cert for development) so I don't get why google needs SHA-1 of my cert, in web browser it doesn't need any thing like that. Is it related to some security like redirection url in web browser?
Thanks!